# I Have Unity Vuforia Black Pink Screen Problem

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I tried the Vuforia in Unity. I set Up the Vuforia SDK and add an AR Camera. When I open it on the computer, I get a pink screen and when I open it on Android, a black screen. I can't solve this.

These are the debug messages:

- MissingMethodException: string[] UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.GetVirtualRealitySDKs(UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup)
  Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaBehaviourEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at :0)
  UnityEditor.UIElements.InspectorElement+<>c__DisplayClass58_0.b__0 () (at <0e1d400b1018464a8ba7b96152b966e8>:0)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

- Shader error in 'Custom/VideoBackground': Unexpected #endif directive. at /Unity Project/V20D/Library/PackageCache/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@8.6.10/Vuforia/Shaders/VuforiaVideoBackground.cginc(27)
  Compiling Fragment program with VUFORIA_RGB
  Platform defines: UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_NO_CUBEMAP_ARRAY UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF2 SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA UNITY_LIGHTMAP_DLDR_ENCODING
  Disabled keywords: VUFORIA_YUVNV12 VUFORIA_YUVNV21 VUFORIA_YUV420P VUFORIA_YUVYV12 UNITY_ENABLE_NATIVE_SHADOW_LOOKUPS UNITY_METAL_SHADOWS_USE_POINT_FILTERING UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF3 UNITY_NO_FULL_STANDARD_SHADER UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2 UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_HALF_PRECISION_FRAGMENT_SHADER_REGISTERS UNITY_LIGHTMAP_RGBM_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR UNITY_VIRTUAL_TEXTURING UNITY_PRETRANSFORM_TO_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION UNITY_ASTC_NORMALMAP_ENCODING
- Could not connect pins - RenderStream()
- Error capturing camera feed. Maybe the camera has been disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

Pink in unity usually means no texture. The fact that it covers your entire screen could indicate that your camera is very close to the untextured object. Try adding a shader to your object and play with your camera position a little.